# How to handle displaying active and inactive data in a list from back end server

Tags: asp.net, angular

I want to know what is the best way to handle active and inactive data that will be shown on a list.

For example, I currently have a list of products (this is with pagination) that will show only active ones by default. There is a toggle button that allows the user to view the ones that are inactive.

My specific question is, how do I handle or call the data from the back end? Do I load both active and inactive data at the same time or do I load the active ones first then only load inactive when user has clicked the toggle button?

I have tried the latter but have encountered an error to which it would end up in a loop calling back end API's.

My goal is to be able to display data correctly without problems in performance. Thank you

EDIT:

So I reviewed my code last night and realized it was really bad (probably had a brainfart)

This is a snippet of my datasource that is being passsed to an angular material table

```
export class ProductsDataSource implements DataSource<Product> {

  productsSubject = new BehaviorSubject<Product[]>([]);

  load(page: PageQuery, isActive: boolean) {
    this.store.pipe(
      select(isActive ? selectActiveProductsPage(page) : selectAllProductsPage(page)),
      tap((products: Product[]) => {
        if (!!products&& products.length > 1) {
          this.productsSubject.next(products);
        } else {
          this.store.dispatch(new ProductsPageRequested({page, isActive}));
        }
      })
    ).subscribe(() => this.loadingService.stopComponentLoading());
  }
}
```

the "isActive" boolean is the trigger on when the inactive data will be shown.

the line 
`this.store.dispatch(new ProductsPageRequested({page, isActive}));`

calls a service method

```
getPage(pageIndex: number, pageSize: number, isActive: boolean): Observable<Product[]> {
    return this.http.get<Product[]>(
      this.baseUrl + `/products/${pageIndex}/${pageSize}/active=${isActive ? 1 : 0}`,
      {headers: this.headers});
  }
```

Comment: "Do I load both active and inactive data at the same time" - it depends on how much data you have. Also you can provide more information about the context, code etc.

Comment: I would say write one endpoint and based on active and inactive send the data back to the frontend.

Comment: @robert Hello, please check my updated question for an example of the code

Comment: @DarwinZaldarriaga code looks ok. How much data you receive from /products... http get?

Comment: You're doing pagination right. So why would you need to care about performance of loading active and inactive at the same time?  Your server will only return the rows in the current page size regardless of active status.  I would keep it simple.  observe any change to the table state (pagination of active filter), on state change call the service and display the results.

Answer (score 0):

Since pagination is enabled, I believe one call doesn't fetch too many records at once. So loading active and inactive before the user selects inactive is not a very bad option.

But if you are concerned about the performance optimization to each bit, Lazily loading the Inactive dataset is the best option.

You have not mentioned how you are showing the data / how the code is. So, Cant see why the API Calls are going in a loop. But it might be an issue with how the calls are triggered.